# How to change selection on previously selected date to current date in Kendo datepicker?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-datepicker

Datepicker's default value and selection is set as current date.

My requirement is that each time when adding, Datepicker's value and selection should be shown on current date in the datepicker.

Here the problem is after saving data with a date and again when trying to add data, datepicker's value is changed to current date. 
But the selection is still on the previously selected date.

So, when i submit data with a date and next time again when trying to select the same date, there is no change on the value. 
It's value still as current date.

```
 @(Html.UI().DatePickerFor(m => m.InvoiceDate)
                         .Value(new DateTime())
                         .Events(e => e.Change("onInvDateChange"))
                         .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 110px;" })
             )
```

[image]

Comment: Remove `.Value(new DateTime())` from your date picker code and add it in `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: I removed it. But still no change on the datepicker.

Comment: In the `onInvDateChange` function call this again `@(Html.UI().DatePickerFor(m => m.InvoiceDate)
                         .Value(new DateTime())
                         .Events(e => e.Change("onInvDateChange"))
                         .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 110px;" })
             )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code inside onClick function of Add button:

```
$('#InvoiceDate').data('kendoDatePicker').value(new Date());
```